# php explode only first var element

Tags: php, arrays

So after some hours of research I didn´t find the solution to this:

```
$data1 = $_POST['dats'];
$sign = $_POST['sign']; 
$teile = explode("$sign", $data1);

foreach($teile AS $newdat)
  {
  echo'<center><img src="http://somedomain.com/&text=',$newdat[0],'"></center></br>';
}
```

The foreach shows only the first number (ex. 1) but the array contains numbers like 1234.
So the rest (234) is cutet off

Thanks for your help

Comment: can you give an example of what $data1 and $sign might be?

Comment: There is no single Array in your piece of code..

Comment: $newdat maybe working instead of $newdat[0]

Comment: $data1 be like 1234,4234,534,234234,6456 and $sign can be ","

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `$newdat` is string only, not array.

```
foreach($teile AS $newdat) {
    echo'<center><img src="http://somedomain.com/&text=',$newdat,'"></center></br>';
}                                                           // ^^ remove '[0]'
```

Comment: @panther Haha I retract that statement, I may have had too much to drink

Answer (score 2):

in foreach use $newdat for $newdat[0]

Answer (score 0):

> Use index value of array

```
$data1 = $_POST['dats'];
$sign = $_POST['sign']; 
$teile = explode("$sign", $data1);

foreach($teile AS $key=>$newdat)
  {
   echo'<center><img src="http://somedomain.com/&text=',$newdat[$key],'"></center></br>';
  }
```

Comment: Which way is better this or use $newdat for $newdat[0]?

Comment: Both ways are better.There is not any issue related to any kind of performance whether you use "key"/"index" value or not.Key value can be used if you want to display particular element.